# Container memory keeps growing, while application and top report stable memory

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, cgroups

I have a nodejs app running inside the docker container on AWS ECS. The memory reported keeps growing like a memory leak, with the traffic. The more traffic, the fast it grows. However, after inspecting the memory with top and free -m inside the instance, the memory (rss) is stable and way below the docker stats.

Going inside the instance in bash, here is the memory from the cgroup: the rss + cache + swap is very close to the memory from `top`, and also from `os.memoryUsage().rss` within the nodejs, but it is too far from memory.usage_in_bytes. How could that possible?

```
root@ip-10-1-10-197:/app# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.kmem.usage_in_bytes 
192913408
root@ip-10-1-10-197:/app# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.usage_in_bytes 
280588288
root@ip-10-1-10-197:/app# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat           
cache 8192
rss 86421504
rss_huge 0
shmem 0
mapped_file 0
dirty 0
writeback 0
swap 0
pgpgin 199618711
pgpgout 199597610
pgfault 358572897
pgmajfault 0
inactive_anon 0
active_anon 86396928
inactive_file 4096
active_file 4096
unevictable 0
hierarchical_memory_limit 536870912
hierarchical_memsw_limit 9223372036854771712
total_cache 8192
total_rss 86421504
total_rss_huge 0
total_shmem 0
total_mapped_file 0
total_dirty 0
total_writeback 0
total_swap 0
total_pgpgin 199618711
total_pgpgout 199597610
total_pgfault 358572897
total_pgmajfault 0
total_inactive_anon 0
total_active_anon 86396928
total_inactive_file 4096
total_active_file 4096
total_unevictable 0
```

Comment: In kernel Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt you will find the following text:

> The main "kmem" counter is fed into the main counter, so kmem charges will
also be visible from the user counter.

Answer (score 0):

The kernel memory usage + rss is very close to memory.usage, and the kernel memory usage keeps growing

If I drop the kernal cach by `echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, the memory immediately goes down.

So the kernel memory cache is not counted in the cgroup's memory stat's cache.